# How to create different rdds based on different record data

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to create different RDDs based on input file with different record types defined in the first two bytes

Input file has

```
00~08-30-2018~001
01~Amwell~000048.00~by~0000~test
02~002~145~West ~23.78
99~001~004
```

How to create RDDs based on the first 2 bytes?

Comment: what do you mean by first 2 bytes? can you explain? if possible can you share the expected output?

Comment: the input file contains the following data :   line 1 has 01~08-30-2018~001 line 2 has 01~Amwell~000048.00~by~0000~test line 3 has 02~002~145~West ~23.78 99~001~004 all the records that start with 01 I want to put in one RDD and all the records that start with 02 I want to put in another RDD.

Answer (score 0):

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("yourtestdatapath")
val rdd01 = rdd.filter(i => i.split("~")(0) == "01")
val rdd02 = rdd.filter(i => i.split("~")(0) == "02")
```

//rdd01 will contain the data starts with 01
//rdd02 will contain the data starts with 02

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Rafael please accept the answer if you find it useful